# How do you force PEAR to download alpha/beta dependencies automatically?

Tags: php, pear

When installing a package from PEAR, if the package is in alpha or beta mode, you can add a suffix to the package name to install the appropriate version; for example, running

```
sudo pear install openid
```

fails, but

```
sudo pear install openid-alpha
```

works.

But how about dependencies?  In the example above, the OpenID in PEAR depends on 4 other packages that are also in alpha/beta.

Is there a way to make PEAR load the alpha/beta dependencies without manually installing each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pear config-set preferred_state alpha
```