# ID3 on cpanel 58

Tags: php, cpanel, pecl, id3

how to install id3 on cpanel v58 with easyapache4 ?

I'm trying to install with WHM PHP Pecl but I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to download pecl/id3 within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.2, stability "alpha", use "channel://pecl.php.net/id3-0.2" to install
install failed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you force PEAR to download alpha/beta dependencies automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017641/how-do-you-force-pear-to-download-alpha-beta-dependencies-automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pear id3 preferred_state alpha
```

or

```
pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/id3-0.2
```

[Command line installer (PEAR)](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php)